# 404 Live Server Error on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Live Server extension by Ritwick Dey on VS Code, but when I load it live. it shows the following error:

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>   127.0.0.1 Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.10

looks like it can't find the path, previously it was working fine. Please help me fix it. Thanks

edit:
If I deactivate xampp this error shows, don't know if it has to do anything with it, but hope this helps:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80  at
>   TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1161:14)

Comment: Looks like folder or file you're trying to access doesn't exists, server should be started. Please double check that and provide more information.

Comment: I opened my project folder, therein is an index.html file. I installed above stated extension and click on go to live. This error pops up

Comment: Server is started as well.

Comment: If you right click your index.html in Explorer to the right of VS Code and you click **Open with Live Server** you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes, either right click and open live server or there is Go Live button below VS Code bar

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem when I used the live sever to browse my index.html page, but I fixed that finally. It turns out that I have open one folder in the vscode, and I just pull the new index.html into the vscode and check it, but this index.html file is not in the folder that I just turn on in the vscode, so when I run the live server to preview the web page I got the 404Not Find warning, so I turn off the original folder and open the folder that the index.html file in it, I run it again and I successfully got the web page I wanted to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XAMPP server you should put your files inside `htdocs` folder, usually located to `c:\xampp\htdocs`. Server is running, the problem is it cannot found files because it's trying to access to the wrong folder.

Comment: Still the same error. It doesn't has any backend file like .php, .py to move them there. 
I used it before and it was able to run anywhere regardless of their location.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're just html files, if you plan to use a XAMPP server to load your project you should put all files inside `htdocs` folder, because `localhost` point to that folder to grab data. Try to start XAMPP Apache, then locate an index.html in your `htdocs` folder, then manually access `http://localhost:port/index.html`. Port is usually 80 but it depends.

Comment: Already did bro, I tried it. I put all files in htdocs still not working, same error

Comment: I think the information provided is not enough to get to a solution. It's very weird that if you put an index.html file inside `htdocs` and you access to `http://localhost/index.html` it doesn't show up. Something is wrong on running XAMPP. Is Apache running? Is it setup to port 80? Or something else?

Comment: Port of Apache is 80 and MySQL 3306